# "Closure" in Javascript using object references: where are "private variables" stored?

Tags: javascript, closures

Disclaimer: this may be a silly question, but it's something that has got me confused while studying Javascript.

I recently ran across the paradigmatic method to create private variables using closure in Javascript, namely using a function that returns an object that has reference to "private variables" through its methods

```
var safebox = function() {
  var _privateVariable = "abcd";
    return {
    "accessFunction":function() {
    return _privateVariable;
    }
}();
safebox.accessFunction(); // "abcd"
```

That is to say, the mechanism of closure maintains the variable `_privateVariable` even after the enclosing function returns.

What happens if the private variable is an object to which a reference is maintained after the enclosing function returns?

```
var safebox = function () {
  var _secretObject = {"secret": "abcd"}
  return {referenceToSecretObject: _secretObject};

}();


console.log(safebox); // "abcd"
safebox.referenceToSecretObject.secret = "def";
console.log(safebox); // "def"
```

Here, as I understand it, ´_secretObject´ still exists, as we have a (shared) reference to it in ´safebox.referenceToSecretObject´.  But this isn't closure (as I understand it).  Is it just what it is, that the variable still exists because there is a reference to it (not garbage collected) even after the function returns?  I am just confused because it seems close in form to closure, but perhaps I'm just seeing some resemblance that is purely coincidental.

Comment: I think the term is, it's stored in the `LexicalEnvironment` of the returned function.

Comment: The object doesn't reference the *variable*. It references the *value* that you assigned to the property (by using the variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the function you have:

- A variable `_secretObject` which has a value that is a reference to an object
- A second object with a property `referenceToSecretObject` which has a reference to the same object

You are calling that function and assigning the return value (the second object) to `safebox`.

At this point the function finishes.

> What happens if the private variable is an object to which a reference is maintained after the enclosing function returns?

**The variable `_secretObject` drops out of scope. There is nothing that can access it. The variable is cleaned up. It no longer exists.**

The object `_secretObject` used to reference still exists because the second object still references it (and the second object is referenced by `safebox`).

If you were to then, for example, `safebox = null` then the reference to the second object would go away.

This would leave 0 references to the second object so it would be garbage collected.

This would get rid of the `referenceToSecretObject` so there would be 0 references to the *first* object.

It is at **this** point that the first object would be garbage collected.

Answer (score -2):

In Javascript there are not such things like `private variables` or `private functions` like in PHP.  The underscore sign is only a convention.

You can play with the closures to kinda have a "private like variable". For instance :

```js
function Foo(bar)
{
  //bar is inside a closure now, only these functions can access it
  this.setBar = function() {bar = 5;}
  this.getBar = function() {return bar;}
  //Other functions
}

var myFoo = new Foo(5);
console.log(myFoo.bar);      //Undefined, cannot access variable closure
console.log(myFoo.getBar()); //Works, returns 5
```

Comment: No but you can force "private" like variables through closure, which OP is asking.

Comment: @JayGould I was updating my answer. Thanks